# Flask - generate url with parameters in html

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to find how I can pass a URL parameter (not request) into the `url_for` function, but I cant find it. In the following example, I need to pass the `q_id` through the form, as I do with `incrRight`. So, how can I have variables in `url_for` in this scenario ?

```html
<form action="{{url_for('answer',q_id='5495eb77433f064294361ceb')}}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="incrRight" value="0">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is what I have on my controller:

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/question/<string:q_id>/answer', methods = ['POST'])
def answer(q_id):
    incrRight = request.form.get('incrRight')
    . . .
```

I need my html form to be able to communicate with the above function, by passing a q_id and the incrRight parameter.

Comment: You mean *query parameters* as formed by the form? You'd have to change the method to `GET` in that case. Or do you mean in the POST body? Either way, you mean for the browser to include them as parameters?

Comment: The form will **not** produce `'../answer/5495eb77433f064294361ceb?incrRight=<incrRight_value>'`. It'll produce `'../answer/5495eb77433f064294361ceb'` with `incrRight=<incrRight_value>` being sent in the POST body, not the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional form parameters by adding more `<input>` tags. If the user of the form is not supposed to changed the items, use a `<input type="hidden">` element:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('answer') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="incrRight" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="5495eb77433f064294361ceb" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This *does* require that the `answer()` view can be invoked without the `q_id` parameter, of course:

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/question/answer', methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/api/v1.0/question/<string:q_id>/answer', methods = ['POST'])
def answer(q_id=None):
    if q_id is None:
        q_id = request.form['q_id']
    incrRight = request.form.get('incrRight')
```

Here a missing `q_id` parameter in the URL signals to the view that the browser included the question id in the POST body instead.

Another option is for you to write JavaScript code that'll adjust the form `action` parameter based on the `q_id` field in the form, but this then requires that your visitors have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: So, if the q_id is compulsory, I need to leave it in "{{ url_for('answer',q_id='dsad21') }}", and also add the input field which will overwrite the hardcoded value ?

Comment: @Giannis: no, the URL is used by your browser to know where to post the form to. Flask will then route to the right view. You'll have to adjust your view registration to accept a post *without the `q_id` parameter*.

Comment: @Giannis: you could put in a special code in the `q_id` field in the URL that you recognize as meaning *look for the question id in the POST body instead*; but in my version I used the absence of a the question id for that instead.

Comment: This is only my first API, but it feels that forcing the q_id as part of URL makes more sense, as 'answer' is an operation applied on a 'question'. The form is only used for the test page of the API, so maybe I should find a different way of testing this function.